# MSE in adaptative filter

Tags: matlab, filters, adaptive-filters

I'm trying to filter some motion noise from an ECG signal. To do that I'll try to implement an adaptive filter using the LMS algorithm.

I think I have to calculate the MSE of this:

`E[e^2 ] = E[(s + n )^2 ]+ 2E[(s + n)X ]W^T + WE[X^T X ]W^T`

in which `s+n` is the noised `ECG`,

`X (n) = [ 1, Accx (n), Accy (n), Accz (n)]` are the values from the accelerometer,

`W = [w0, w1, w2, w3]` the coefficients.

`Wt +1 = Wt + 2αeX`,

I'm trying to understand how to calculate `alfa` and minimise the MSE.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/adaptfilt.lms.html

can anyone give me a simpler example? I'm kind of lost here.

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between `s` (your "noiseless" or "desired" ECG signal) and the accelerometer readings (`X`). Can you point to a model for the relationship?

Comment: @PeterK. I'm trying to remove motion noise from my ECG signal.

Answer (score 1):

This [scilab](http://www.scilab.org/) script implements a simple LMS adaptive filter.

```
M = 50;
LMS = zeros(M,N);
LMS(:,1) = zeros(M,1);
ERR = zeros(1,N);
y = zeros(1,N);
mu = 0.0005;

for t=M:N,
    Uwindowed = u(t - [0:M-1]');
    y(t) = LMS(:,t)'*Uwindowed.';
    ERR(t) = d(t) - y(t);
    LMS(:,t+1) = LMS(:,t) + mu*Uwindowed.'*ERR(t);
end;
```

The inputs to it are `u(t)`, the noisy signal and `d(t)` the desired signal.  For the standard LMS algorithm to work, you need to have an idea of what the noiseless signal looks like.

From your equations:

- $\alpha$ appears to be similar to `mu` (or `mu/2`).
- `u` is your `s+n`.
- I am not sure what your `d` is.
- Your equation for the error is, er, erroneous. :-)